# Equivalent to \nptextcite for biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I need to switch from APA citation to Chicago author-date. One thing that I couldn't find is how to cite within parentheses with other text, for example like this: (see James 2013 for an introduction)

In APA I could use \nptextcite to omit the parentheses but I couldn't find something similar for the biblatex-chicago package. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: I don't think Chicago style distinguishes between citations in parentheses and citations not in parentheses in the way APA style does (which made `\nptextcite` necessary in the first place), so you could probably just use `\cite`.

Comment: That actually solves it! Thanks! When I just use cite, there are no parentheses around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, unlike APA style, Chicago style does not demand a different for citations inside and outside of a pair of parentheses. This distinction is something characteristic of APA style.

So the 'equivalent' of `biblatex-apa`'s `\nptextcite` for `biblatex-chicago` is probably just `\cite`: That will give you a citation without parentheses.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
(see \cite{sigfridsson} for an introduction)

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (see Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998 for an introduction)]

If you are already heavily using `\nptextcite` in your paper and don't want to switch the command in case you go back to `biblatex-apa`, you can add

```
\newcommand*{\nptextcite}{\cite}
\newcommand*{\nptextcites}{\cites}
```

to your preamble.